# How to fix "Failed to start VNC Server in Service Mode Daemon"

Tags: linux, kali-linux, services, vnc

This problem first showed randomly when booting up my Kali Linux laptop, now it doesn't let me get into my desktop and shows me this error.

I can get into tty1 and I tried to start, stop and restart the service there but it still doesn't start.
I also tried to start the desktop environment with startx but it doesn't work, only works in sudo mode and takes me into the sudo user.

When I start it with
`sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service`

And check the status with
`sudo systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service`

I get

```
vncserver-x11-serviced.service - VNC Server in Service Mode daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-08-23 13:18:36 EEST; 6s ago
   Duration: 3ms
    Process: 87427 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 87427 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 2ms

Aug 23 13:18:36 kali systemd[1]: vncserver-x11-serviced.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 23 13:18:36 kali systemd[1]: Stopped VNC Server in Service Mode daemon.
Aug 23 13:18:36 kali systemd[1]: vncserver-x11-serviced.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 23 13:18:36 kali systemd[1]: vncserver-x11-serviced.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 13:18:36 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start VNC Server in Service Mode daemon.
```

I searched for hours on the internet and the only similar problem I could find was a post on Reddit where the same problem was happening with someone on Manjaro.

Comment: Damn! I got so excited to see my exact problem. So, naturally, over a year with no answers. I'm beginning to believe it's because it's literally not possible to get vnc working on linux. It has been HOURS and I have not seen a single answer to this problem. WHY IS THIS SO HARD?